# Активация стандартных всплывающих подсказок <form> после изменения значения с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Возникла проблема с всплывающими подсказками `<form>`. После изменения значения с помощью JS, подсказка, привязанная к `minlength`, перестаёт появляться. При этом она перестаёт появляться и в том случае, если тегу `<input>` добавить атрибут `value`.

Код представлен ниже:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("tel-number");
input.value = "8";
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" id="tel-number" name="tel-number" minlength="11" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Если убрать строку с присвоением значения, то подсказка начнёт работать:

[image: всплывающая подсказка]

Отмечу, что использование JS и изменение значения с его помощью мне необходимо.

Comment: Библиотеку для маски телефона не пробовали использовать? Например, imask.js. Надеяться на валидацию браузера и его подсказки не очень надежно - хотя бы событие input что ли.

Comment: Возможно придётся писать свою валидацию. У html это кривотня с самого завода и её не обойти без танцев с бубном...... либо maskinput использовать

Comment: @Arbery, код - просто пример. На самой же странице я использую скрипт, который как раз работает с помощью Listener. Проблема именно в том, что оставшаяся часть формы использует стандартные подсказки браузера.  Но похоже, что придётся менять подход. 
Спасибо за Ваш комментарий и редактирование вопроса!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, понял. Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Comment: похоже проблема именно с `min/maxlength` атрибутами - в них учитывается только [последнее **изменение пользователем**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261163/2881286)

Comment: а по-моему, в chrome продолжает работать, тупенько и с тормозом, но если поводить мышью, то через несколько секунд предупреждение появляется. Т.е. может после прочтения кучи документации и глубоких размышлений и улучшите как-нибудь, но не точно и не 100% кроссбраузерно. Поэтому проще забыть и ручками быстрее что-нибудь написать.